# How to limit access to specyfic folder in django-cms, filer, FilerImageField?

Tags: django-cms

```
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField

class Brand(models.Model):
    """ Brand """
    logo = FilerImageField(verbose_name=_('Logo'), blank=True, null=True)
```

This small peace of code are storing logo images (django-cms, filer). In admin I have access to all tree of folders, but in this case I would like to limit access only to "logos" folder. Any ideas how to do this?